# r blastula - not rendering rmarkdown correctly in the body of gmail

Tags: r, base64, gmail, blastula

I'm learning the `blastula` package in `r` for sending `rmarkdown` files in the body of an email. This is the code I use:

```
rmd_email <- render_email('my_rmarkdown.Rmd')

rmd_email %>%
  smtp_send(
    from = "name@gmail.com",
    to = "name@gmail.com",
    subject = "report",
    credentials = creds_key(id = "gmail")
  )
```

However, the `rmarkdown` document is not being rendered correctly in the body of the emails I get. It seems that gmail is not decoding the `base64` text:

[image: The email I get]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got a solution. Just format the metadata when creating the `rmarkdown` document. So, instead of

```
---
output: html_document
---
```

use the following:

```
---
output: blastula::blastula_email 
---
```